# Apache Flink batch mode fails after a few minutes and prints the results

Tags: java, apache-flink

I'm reading CSV file using Apache Flink and then transform records into a table from which I execute SQL query and print the results to stdout.

Code (simplified):

```
 StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment(1);
 env.setRuntimeMode(RuntimeExecutionMode.BATCH);

 rowDataStreamSource = env.readFile(...).disableChaining();

 final StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env);
 final Table table = tableEnv.fromChangelogStream(rowDataStreamSource, ordersSchema, ChangelogMode.insertOnly());
 tableEnv.createTemporaryView("orders", table);

 Table originalSQL = tableEnv.sqlQuery(...)
 originalSQL.execute().print();

 env.execute();
```

After running this job I get an error after a few minutes:

> 21:29:49.999
> [deploy.instance_IS_UNDEFINED,,,][mini-cluster-io-thread-3] INFO
> o.a.f.r.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcService - Stopping Akka RPC service.
> 21:29:50.066 [deploy.instance_IS_UNDEFINED,,,][http-nio-8080-exec-1]
> WARN  o.a.f.s.a.o.c.CollectResultFetcher - Failed to get job status so
> we assume that the job has terminated. Some data might be lost.
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: MiniCluster is not yet running or has
> already been shut down.   at
> org.apache.flink.util.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:193)
> at
> org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniCluster.getDispatcherGatewayFuture(MiniCluster.java:877)

And then table with my sql results is printed just below the exception.

What causes the problem here? Is there a way to tell Flink there are no more records so it can finish the job and print the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `FileSource` rather than `readFile` in order to have this work correctly in batch execution mode: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/org/apache/flink/connector/file/src/FileSource.html

Or, even better, you can directly use SQL to define a table acting as a source to ingest the input files, as described here: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/connectors/table/filesystem/

Comment: Actually the problem occurs only when running job in local environment. After submitting to external Job manager the problem dissapears.